# Make a React WebPage for local use

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, offline

I started coding recently in JavaScript and started to make a little WebPage that's am gonna present it to a Client.The thing is that you need a server to run the webPage, I can't make the client open one each time ... (I could have gone for another language to make it Offline and easier, but I wanted to try JS for the GUI and performance).

So I thought about making some sort of a .bat file to open the server,Open the html file,when html is closed, the servers shuts down.(I know NOTHING about .bat files...)

after a little research I found that I can do it using Python and it's easy,but even then , I have to install Py. on the clients computer and I want to avoid that.

And more over, I found that my App doesn't work on Python's server or for the LiveServer extention from VS Code. (Yes I am new to React, I used npm to download a WebPackage, Used 'npm start' for the server and it works fine, it must be a probleme in the html when when importing js or when using ReactDOM.render).

This might be a little complicated but please if anyone have a suggestion then I will be grateful.

Comment: If hosting is your problem use some static file hosting like https://zeit.co/now , https://surge.sh/

Comment: Boobalan, Thanks for the links , but it's for local usage not online.I don't want to deploy it on the net since there's a high chance the client won't have internet the moment he will use it + it's functionalities doesn't need internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using create-react-app, You can run `yarn build` and it will create the production build in your build folder. just run index.html in a browser and it will run the website without any server.

Comment: I don't use yarn, but what does realy do this command ? I didn't find a good documentation but : will I be able to keep developing the app after ?

Comment: Yes you can use `npm run build` to build production build

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I still don't know why I need a test server in the developement , but I used 'npm run build' and it worked fine without any server

Comment: Well the thing is npm run build command takes time to create a minified JavaScript but if you use a server for development it does not create a minified file that can be executed by the browser (performance is slow in development because of that) and also you need server to compile all react files everytime you make changes using webpack

Comment: When i open the index, the screen in completely blank

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Electron it helps you to build cross-platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

I've used phpDesktop for building a desktop application using PHP, but this is better in every aspect.

[ElectronJS Homepage](https://electronjs.org/)

[This is a great Electron Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN1Czs0m1SU)

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I will search more about this and hope it will fix the probleme.